# why is this DOM code not appearing on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a homework where I have to make a page containing 10 books with some info about them and images of their covers using DOM, even though I linked the JS file to the HTML file, I can't see anything when I open my HTML file in the browser.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
'use strict';

{

  const booksObj = {
    how_to_create_a_mind: {
      title: 'How to Create a Mind: The Secret of Human Thought Revealed',
      author: 'Ray Kurzweil',
      language: 'english',
    },
    universe_from_nothing: {
      title: 'A Universe from Nothing',
      author: 'Lawrence M. Krauss',
      language: 'english',
    },
    sapiens: {
      title: 'Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind',
      author: 'Yuval Noah Harari',
      language: 'english',
    },
    homo_deus: {
      title: 'Homo Deus: A Brief History of Tomorrow',
      author: 'Yuval Noah Harari',
      language: 'english',
    }
  };


  const root = document.getElementById('root');

  function booksList() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    root.appendChild(div);
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    div.appendChild(h1);
    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('My List Of Books'));

    for (const key in booksObj) {
      const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
      root.appendChild(h2);
      h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['title']));
      const author = document.createElement('p');
      root.appendChild(author);
      author.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['author']));
      const language = document.createElement('p');
      root.appendChild(language);
      language.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['language']));
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      root.appendChild(img);
      img.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['images']));
      img.src = bookImage;
    }
  }
  booksList();
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Open your dev console, do you see any errors?

Comment: what is the `{` after use strict for?

Comment: This is a simple typo-problem. Voting to close

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a `}` at the end of your script.  Check out the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/fwL0vx46/

Your code resulted in an `unexpected end of input` exception which shows in the developer tools console.

Answer (score 0):

There is on curly bracket after your strict syntax. That cause error into your script.

```js
'use strict';
  const bookImage = '';
  const booksObj = {
how_to_create_a_mind: {
  title: 'How to Create a Mind: The Secret of Human Thought Revealed',
  author: 'Ray Kurzweil',
  language: 'english',
},
universe_from_nothing: {
  title: 'A Universe from Nothing',
  author: 'Lawrence M. Krauss',
  language: 'english',
},
sapiens: {
  title: 'Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind',
  author: 'Yuval Noah Harari',
  language: 'english',
},
homo_deus: {
  title: 'Homo Deus: A Brief History of Tomorrow',
  author: 'Yuval Noah Harari',
  language: 'english',
}
  };


  const root = document.getElementById('root');

  function booksList() {
const div = document.createElement('div');
root.appendChild(div);
const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
div.appendChild(h1);
h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('My List Of Books'));

for (const key in booksObj) {
  const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  root.appendChild(h2);
  h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['title']));
  const author = document.createElement('p');
  root.appendChild(author);
  author.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['author']));
  const language = document.createElement('p');
  root.appendChild(language);
  language.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['language']));
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  root.appendChild(img);
  img.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['images']));
  img.src = bookImage;
}
  }
  booksList();
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Note:** I add `const bookImage = '';` to prevent from another error because it's not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';

{

  const booksObj = {
    how_to_create_a_mind: {
      title: 'How to Create a Mind: The Secret of Human Thought Revealed',
      author: 'Ray Kurzweil',
      language: 'english'
    },
    universe_from_nothing: {
      title: 'A Universe from Nothing',
      author: 'Lawrence M. Krauss',
      language: 'english'
    },
    sapiens: {
      title: 'Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind',
      author: 'Yuval Noah Harari',
      language: 'english'
    },
    homo_deus: {
      title: 'Homo Deus: A Brief History of Tomorrow',
      author: 'Yuval Noah Harari',
      language: 'english'
    }
  };


  const root = document.getElementById('root');

  function booksList() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    root.appendChild(div);
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    div.appendChild(h1);
    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('My List Of Books'));

    for (const key in booksObj) {
      const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
      root.appendChild(h2);
      h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['title']));
      const author = document.createElement('p');
      root.appendChild(author);
      author.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['author']));
      const language = document.createElement('p');
      root.appendChild(language);
      language.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['language']));
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      root.appendChild(img);
      let bookImage = img.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['images']));
      img.src = bookImage;
    }
  }
  booksList();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please check and provide feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML part is right, but you put some extra brackets in js file, copy and paste this code.

```
'use strict';

  const booksObj = {
    how_to_create_a_mind: {
      title: 'How to Create a Mind: The Secret of Human Thought Revealed',
      author: 'Ray Kurzweil',
      language: 'english',
      images : ''
    },
    universe_from_nothing: {
      title: 'A Universe from Nothing',
      author: 'Lawrence M. Krauss',
      language: 'english',
      images : ''
    },
    sapiens: {
      title: 'Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind',
      author: 'Yuval Noah Harari',
      language: 'english',
      images : ''
    },
    homo_deus: {
      title: 'Homo Deus: A Brief History of Tomorrow',
      author: 'Yuval Noah Harari',
      language: 'english',
      images : ''
    }
  };


  const root = document.getElementById('root');


  function booksList() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    root.appendChild(div);
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    div.appendChild(h1);
    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('My List Of Books'));

    for (const key in booksObj) {
      const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
      root.appendChild(h2);
      h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['title']));
      const author = document.createElement('p');
      root.appendChild(author);
      author.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['author']));
      const language = document.createElement('p');
      root.appendChild(language);
      language.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['language']));
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      root.appendChild(img);
      var bookImage = img.appendChild(document.createTextNode(booksObj[key]['images']));
      img.src = bookImage;
    }
  }

booksList();
```

Comment: And also there was one error in your code, that bookImage is undefined, i have solved this, by declaring this variable, enjoy day !!!